# How to use a variable in the expression of a 'normal' command?

Tags: vimscript, normal-mode

How can one use a variable when executing something via `normal!` in vimscript?

**Example:**

```
function! MyFunction(someArg)
   normal! (a:someArg)l
endfunction
```

This should move the cursor `someArg` steps to the right.

Comment: you need to use `exe "norm!" variable`

Comment: Related : https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `execute` function takes a string as argument, it expands the string and execute it a a regular ex command. Thus you can do:

```
function! MyFunction(someArg) 
    execute "normal! ". a:someArg. "l" 
endfunction
```

The `.` is a standard vimscript operator to concatenate strings.

`execute` can be shortened to `exe`.

See `:h :execute`

---

**EDIT** I'll add a point about the comment of @Christian Brabandt about the concatenation with a `.`.

The doc says:

> Multiple arguments are concatenated, with a space in
>   between.  To avoid the extra space use the "."
>   operator to concatenate strings into one argument.

So the command could be:

```
execute "normal!" a:someArg . "l"
```

The executed command will be:

```
normal! 2l
```

Comment: you don't need the '.'. exe will concatenate strings with a space without it.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Wait seriously? I did not know that.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I didn't know that thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For completeness's sake, I find the string concatenation using `.` is not pleasant to read. We may use [`printf`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#printf()) to concatenate strings and variables for better readability.

```
execute printf("normal! %sl", a:someArg)
```

Comment: And if you expect `a:someArg` to be a count, you can even force that interpretation using `%d` in your printf format.

Answer (score 1):

statox' answer is the best answer but I think the command looks cleaner that way:
(leave spaces between . and strings)

```
let i = 4
execute "normal! " . i . "l"
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!