# Use variables in colorscheme

Tags: colorscheme, variables

I had to notice that this doesn't work:

```
let test=128

highlight Normal ctermbg=test
```

Is it possible to use variables in colorschemes?

Comment: `execute "highlight Normal ctermbg=" . test`

Comment: Note that this is more or less the same question than the one you asked last week http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9644/1841 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vimscript is evaluated exactly like the Ex commands typed in the `:` command-line. There were no variables in `ex`, so there's no way to specify them. When typing a command interactively, you'd probably use `<C-R>=` to insert variable contents:

```
:sleep <C-R>=timetowait<CR>m<CR>
```

... but in a script, `:execute` must be used. All the literal parts of the Ex command must be quoted (single or double quotes), and then concatenated with the variables:

```
execute 'sleep' timetowait . 'm'
```