# Concatination of arguments in vimscript when reading the output of a command to a buffer?

Tags: vimscript, external-command

Is there a way to use a vimscript function to pass arguments to an external command?

I have the following:

```
function! GetJobLines(argA)

    " 1. Create a new buffer for the output
    enew

    " 2. Change directory to location of said script
    cd /home/leeand00/src

    " 3. Run said script with argument (not really but for example)
    read!echo a:argA
endfunction
```

I've also tried:

```
read!"echo" . a:argA
```

Comment: `"` is the comment character in VimL, not `#`.

Comment: Maybe not a complete duplicate but pretty related: [How to use a variable in the expression of a 'normal' command?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9644/1841)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to incorporate the value of a variable into an Ex command is to use the `:execute` command, which concatenates its arguments into a string, then executes that string, like this:

```
:execute "read!echo" a:argA
```

or even better, like this, which includes the use of `shellescape()` to make sure that the characters of `a:argA` are properly quoted for use by the shell:

```
:execute "read!echo" shellescape(a:argA)
```

See

```
:help :execute
:help shellescape()
```