# Passing a # character to the shell in vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, external-command, argument-list

In my [previous question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10837/concatination-of-arguments-in-vimscript-when-reading-the-output-of-a-command-to), I passed an argument into a Vimscript function and concatenated it into the command line.  This works great, but when you pass a string that contains the `#` character, it balks with an error about the following:

```
E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with `:p:h`: read!<shellcmd>
```

The vimscript function looks like this:

```
function! GetJobLines(a:argA)

    " 1. Create a new buffer for the output
    enew

    " 2. Change directory to location of said script
    cd /home/leeand00/src

    execute "read!echo" shellescape(a:argA)

functionend
```

Running the command itself looks like this:

```
:call GetJobLines("C#")
```

Myself I thought that including `shellescape()` would have taken care of this, however this is not the case.  I also tried adding `\#` to escape the `#` character, but that does not work either...

When I run the same command from the command line directly it does not cause an issue, and clearly this is a problem to be corrected in vimscript, I just don't know how.

Comment: A single backslash may not work with double-quoted strings. It really depends on how you're building your command to execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that some characters are considered special by the Vim commandline. In your case, `#` refers to the alternate file name.

You can find the documentation with a full list at [`:help cmdline-special`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline%2dspecial). This also includes the two possible ways to prevent this:

- Prefix it with a backslash:

  ```
  :execute ":read !echo " . shellescape('C\#')
  ```
- Use the `fnameescape()` function:

  ```
  :execute ":read !echo " . shellescape(fnameescape('C#'))
  ```

Answer (score 6):

`shellescape({string}[, {special}])` has an extra, optional argument `{special}` which exists exactly for this purpose.

> When the `{special}` argument is present and it's a non-zero Number or a non-empty String (non-zero-arg), then special items such as "!", "%", and "`<cword>`" will be preceded by a backslash.  This backslash will be removed again by the `:!` command.

Therefore, what you want to use is `:execute ':read !echo' shellescape(a:argA, 1)`.