# Color name or number not recognized: ctermbg

Tags: colorscheme

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Color name or number not recognized: ctermbg=g:extra_whitespace_color guibg=g:extra_whitespace_color
```

Pointing to these lines:

```
let g:extra_whitespace_color = 'black'
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=g:extra_whitespace_color guibg=g:extra_whitespace_color
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=g:extra_whitespace_color guibg=g:extra_whitespace_color
```

when I don't use a variable, everything works but I'm unclear what I'm doing wrong.

```
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=black guibg=black
```

Comment: [Potential duplicate](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9644/1841)

Answer (score 2):

Variable interpolation is not automatic in certain contexts.

Use

```
execute printf('highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=%s guibg=%s', g:extra_whitespace_color, g:extra_whitespace_color)
```