# How do I use a variable or return value in option, command, or mapping?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, options, variables, string-manipulation

I have a variable `foo` with `let foo='value'`, and a function `F` like

```
function F()
  return 'value'
endfunction
```

and I want to use them

- in an option: `:set option=foo`, `:set option=F()`; or
- in a command: `:edit foo`, `:edit F()`; or
- in a mapping: `:nnoremap f :foo<CR>`, `:nnoremap f :F()<CR>`

How can I do this? In other words, how can I reference variables as command arguments?

Comment: Thank you for the work you put on your answer but isn't the question a duplicate of [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9644/1841)? Clearly your answer is more complete than mine but I think the question is still the same :)

Comment: @statox here’s the [meta](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1486/10604)—i dont disagree with you though

Comment: Oh right I forgot about this meta

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason your example attempts don't work is that in many locations text is simply seen as a literal string, rather than VimScript. So functions, variables, and the like don't work.

For example, if you do:

```
:let var='value'
:set option=var
```

Then Vim will simply set the value of `option` to the literal value `var`, since it doesn't recognize VimScript in `:set`. The same applies to `:map` and many other locations.

In general, most colon/Ex/`:` commands do not evaluate VimScript.

#### `:execute`

Not all is lost, since you can still build a string with `:execute`:

```
:let var='value'
:execute ':set option=' . var
```

The `:execute` command executes the given VimScript expression. In this case, we build a string using the variable, and what `:execute` sees is `:set option=value`.

---

You can use any Vim expression; some more examples:

```
" Function return value
:execute 'set option=' . Fun()

" You don't need to use string concatenation; all arguments are 
" concatenated automatically. A space is added.
:execute 'edit' var
:execute 'edit' Fun()
```

---

`map` expands special key sequences like `<CR>`. To get them in an execute, you need to prepend the `<` with a `\`: `"\<CR>"`. You *need* to use double quotes, single quotes won't work:

```
:let key = 'h'
:execute 'nnoremap ' . key . " :echo 'hello'\<CR>"
```

Because you're building VimScript code in a VimScript string things tend to look rather ugly. C'est la vie. Depending on your personal tastes, `printf()` can make things a bit easier on the eyes:

```
:execute printf("nnoremap %s :echo 'hello'\<CR>", key)
```

Note: it's very common to abbreviate `:execute` to `:exe`.

See [`:help :execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) for more information.

#### Expression mappings

Finally, you can use expression mappings to use a Vim expression for the entire right-hand side.

```
" Execute the contents of the current line as a Vim command.
:nnoremap <expr> f getline('.')
```

The biggest difference with `:execute` is that the expression is run when the key is pressed, and not when the command is defined. So every time you press `f` in the above example `getline()` gets the value of the current line. If we had used:

```
:execute ':nnoremap f' getline('.')
```

Then it would get the value of the line *once*. So if you had been on the line `gg` it would be the same as typing:

```
:nnoremap f gg
```

See [`:help :map-<expr>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-%3Cexpr%3E) for more information.

Interactively and in mappings, the expression register `"=` can be used to achieve similar effects. Its usage stands out as

```
:nnoremap keys :put =Fun()<CR>
```

or

```
:inoremap keys <C-r>=Fun()<CR>
```

---

#### `:let-&`

As a special case with options, you can use

```
:let &option = 'value'
```

syntax to have a similar effect as

```
:execute 'set option='.value
```

Comment: A few random remarks: 1. You can also use the `&`, `&l:`, `&g:` scopes to assign the contents of a variable to an option: `:let &option = var` (see `:h expr-option`). 2. If you want to know whether you can pass the contents of a variable to a command without `:exe`, check out its synopsis in the help.

Comment: E.g.: at `:h :let-&`, you can see that the rhs is `{expr1}`. And a variable is an expression (because it's listed in the `expr9` block at `:h expression-syntax`, and `expr9` is listed in the `expr8` block, and the `expr8` block is listed in the `expr7` block, and so on until the `expr1` block; IOW `expr1` is the most general type of expressions which includes all types of expressions including simple variables). OTOH, the synopsis of `:set` given at `:h set-args` doesn't mention `{expr}` but `{value}`. A variable is not a value, so you can't directly pass a variable name to `:set`.

Comment: 3. The string concatenation operator can be implicit, but fwiw, I always write it explicitly (using it implicitly made me write it in places where it doesn't work; e.g. `:let v='x' 'y'`). And if your Vim is recent enough, use `..` instead of `.` (see `:h scriptversion-2` for the reason why).

Comment: 4. `:execute 'nnoremap ' . key . " :echo 'hello'\<CR>"`: you don't need the backslash, because mapping (and menu) commands automatically translate special sequences such as `<CR>` when populating the mappings table. This is also why you don't write `:nnoremap cd :echo 'hello'\<CR>` but `:nnoremap cd :echo 'hello'<CR>`. But if the command inside the string passed to `:exe` was not `:nnoremap`, e.g. `:normal`, then you would need the backslash, because `:norm` doesn't automatically translate special sequences.

Comment: @user938271 That is not really an implicit string concatenation, it's `:execute` which takes multiple arguments and splits all of them into words. That's very specific to `:execute`, but I'd say it's well known to work in `:execute`, so I think it's often preferable to an explicit string concatenation with the extra spaces needed to make that work...

Comment: @filbranden You're right, it's specific to `:exe`. I still prefer an explicit concatenation operator to be consistent with other commands which don't concatenate their arguments; just my two cents. Edit: Ah no, `:echo` does it too, so it's not specific to `:exe`.

Comment: As the question does not ask specifically about scripting, I think that interactive input using expression register is worth mentioning.

Comment: @Matt done—would welcome suggestions or edits.

Comment: @user938271 I've addressed some of your points, though others (`..` and `\\`) may confuse the point.