# switch current directory between a base directory and current file directory

Tags: vimscript, variables, working-directory

**Goal:**
To achieve filename/path completion relative to current file directory using file name completion `CTRL-X CTRL-F`.

I open all my files contained in a base directory such that `:pwd` in *some_file* outputs `/some/path/to/base_directory`. This lets me search for other files relative to base_directory, that I want.

The problem with using `CTRL-X CTRL-F` is that by default it prompts for filename/directory relative to base_directory. So, if one has to use a path name that is relative to current file directory, something like `../../../some_file` pathname, one is out of luck, as this path name is of *some_file* in three directory level up from *base_directory*.

I am trying to write a mapping that can switch between *base_directory* and current file directory to make efficient use of `CTRL-X CTRL-F`.

---

**Attempt:**

```
" temporarily switch to current file directory
function! SwitchCwd()
  " on first execution of function from a window
  if exists("w:baseCwd")==0
    " store the base directory path in w:baseCwd
    let w:baseCwd=getcwd()
    let w:tmpCwd=expand("%:p:h")
    " when this mapping is run first time from a window, switch to current file directory
    lcd %:p:h
  elseif w:tmpCwd==expand("%:p:h")
    echo w:baseCwd
    " on subsequent executions of this function from same window
    w:tmpCwd=w:baseCwd
    " switch to base directory
    lcd w:baseCwd
  else
    echo "inside else"
    lcd %:p:h
  endif
endfunction

"Path prompt mapping
nnoremap <leader>cd :call SwitchCwd()<CR>
```

When I run this mapping with `<leader>cd` for the first time, vim successfully switches to current file directory.

Any subsequent command `<leader>cd` results in **error:**

```
Error detected while processing function SwitchCwd:
line   13:
E13: File exists (add ! to override)
line   14:
E344: Can't find directory "w:baseCwd" in cdpath
E472: Command failed
```

`echo w:baseCwd` in `elseif` outputs the correct absolute path of *base_directory*, but throws an error in assignment `w:tmpCwd=w:baseCwd`.

Comment: you need to use `:execute` to interpolate variables. This is likely a duplicate.

Comment: How to implement `:execute` in this questions context?

Comment: @HasloVardos use `execute 'lcd' w:baseCwd` for the command that goes back to the top directory...

Comment: @filbranden I replaced `lcd w:baseCwd` with `execute 'lcd' w:baseCwd`. This works during first execution of function and successfully changes `:pwd` to current file directory. During second execution it changes `:pwd` back to the top directory but also throws  **error**: *E13: File exists (add ! to override)*. It keeps on throwing this error in subsequent executions.

Comment: More on execute: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate issues in your code:

1. In most situations, if you want to use the *contents* of a variable in a Vim command, you need to use `:execute` to achieve this. `lcd w:baseCwd` will attempt to change to a directory named `w:baseCwd`. To change to the directory currently stored in that variable, use `:execute 'lcd' w:baseCwd`.
2. You cannot assign to a variable simply by writing `x = y`. You need to use `:let`. The line `w:tmpCwd=w:baseCwd` doesn't assign to a variable: it attempts to write the current buffer to the file `:tmpCwd=w:baseCwd`. The first time you do this, it will succeed. The second time you do it (with a different buffer) it will fail with the `File Exists` error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
" Toggles CWD with the currently opened file and base directory
function ToggleCWD()
    if !exists("w:actual_wd")
        let w:actual_wd = getcwd()
        lcd %:p:h
        pwd
    else
        execute "lcd" w:actual_wd
        unlet w:actual_wd
        pwd
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>cd :call ToggleCWD()<CR>
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!