# Return value to custom function

Tags: neovim, plugin-nerdtree

I'm writting a function to integrates [NERDTree](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree) with [Ack](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim).
The goal is to create a "Find in Directory".

I create this:

```
function! Fif_NERDTreeGetPath()
  let nodePath = g:NERDTreeFileNode.GetSelected().path.str()
  return nodePath
endfunction
:command! -nargs=+ Fif :Ack "<args>" Fif_NERDTreeGetPath()
```

The function `Fif_NERDTreeGetPath()` returns the correct path for the directory that cursor is on.

But, when I execute `Fif word` it return:

`:ack -s -H --nopager --nocolor --nogroup --column "word" Fif_NERDTreeGetPath()`

It's almost right. The problem is the path is not being returned. I'm expecting something like:

`:ack -s -H --nopager --nocolor --nogroup --column "word" /path/to/directory/`

This is my first vim function. I don't know how to solve. Tks!

Comment: you need execute: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Tks, `execute` solves. The final command for Find In Files with NERDTree and Ack.vim is: `:command! -nargs=+ Fif let node_path = g:NERDTreeFileNode.GetSelected().path.str() | :execute "normal! \<c-w>\<c-w>" | :execute ':Ack "<args>" ' . node_path` . When I position the cursor on the NerdTree directory node, I run `:Fif keyword` and everything works fine.