# add python option in vimrc

Tags: variables, filetype-fortran

For my `fortran ft` I use

```
au BufWritePre <buffer> :silent %!fprettify --silent
```

in my `ftplugin`.

The [fprettify](https://github.com/pseewald/fprettify) is a `python` script with many `command line options`, using `argparse`.

Now, my question is, is it possible to set those option in vimrc and use the string using let in my `ftplugin`?

e.g.
in `.vimrc`:

```
 fprettify_options = "--silent --strict-indent"
```

and in my `ftplugin`:

```
 let g:fprettify_options = get (g:, fprettify_options, "--strict")
 au BufWritePre <buffer> :silent %!fprettify g:fprettify_options
```

I am getting  error:

```
directory g:fprettify_options does not exist!
```

This is probably because `fprettify g:fprettify_options`.

How can I pass the values to `fprettify`?

Comment: See also https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `:execute` command to be able to construct command out of strings:

```
let g:fprettify_options = get (g:, fprettify_options, "--strict")
au BufWritePre <buffer> :execute 'silent %!fprettify ' . g:fprettify_options
```

Here I have just wrapped your example with `:execute` and a string concatenation.

`'silent %!fprettify ' . g:fprettify_options` would become `'silent %!fprettify --strict'` and executed with `execute`.