# Use variable in vim mapping async task

Tags: key-bindings, variables

I am trying to use a variable in this mapping:

```
let board_ip = "192.168.100.18"                                                                      │
nnoremap <F6> :AsyncRun echo . board_ip . > /dev/pts/1 2>&1<CR>
```

But I cannot get it working, getting board_ip echoed all the time.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26460/add-python-option-in-vimrc/26461#26461

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:execute` to run a command made out of strings:

```
let g:board_ip = "192.168.100.18"
nnoremap <F6> :execute "AsyncRun echo " . g:board_ip . " > /dev/pts/1 2>&1"<CR>
```