# How do you use a variable as argument to another vim command?

Tags: vimscript

I have the following function:

```
fu! EditFileInBrowser()
  let l:url = @+
  let l:url = substitute(l:url, 'http:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1:4000\/', '', '')
  let l:url = substitute(l:url, '/$', '', 'g')
  let l:url = substitute(l:url, '-', ' ', 'g')
  let l:file = '~/vimwiki/webnotes/' . l:url . '.md'
  echom l:file
  edit l:file
endfu
```

It keeps trying to edit the string `l:file`. I want to edit the value of the variable `l:file`, of course.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there another way to do this, though?

```
edit `=l:file`
```

See also `` :h `= ``

Answer (score 1):

Figures tha after 20 min. of looking for an answer I find it 1 min after posting this:

`execute "edit " . l:file`

Is there another way to do this, though? Seems weird.