# Use normal command output as variable

Tags: functions, macro

I want to be able to use some normal commands I tend to use in the day to day as an input for another function, for example `4X`, I would like `4X` to be expanded to `XXXX` and then use it in a function as `:substitude(s, 'here', <expand result of 4X>, 'g')`

It's there an easy way to set this up?

Comment: To me this is a duplicate of [How do I use a variable or return value in option, command, or mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/1841)

Comment: 2 points: the command is `:substitute`, and it has an eponymous function `substitute()`; the command can be run with a colon, but does not use left/right parens like a function—it uses a delimiter character to separate pattern/replacement/flags. The function uses parens, and must be `:call`ed or appear in an expression position (like after `:echo` or on the right-hand side of a `:let`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this specific case, you have `repeat(4, 'X')`.

Otherwise, normal and command mode commands don't return anything. They may echo messages (which we can get with `execute()`), or they can do any kind of action (compile, move cursor, change focus, open/close buffers/windows, change the buffer...). We can't provide a generic answer to your question as there is none.

What are your specific use cases? `repeat()`. What else?

Comment: On this case repeat works just fine, I believe that there most be plenty of vim functions I just need to get to know for each use case but this one tackles the issue perfectly. Thanks for the quick answer!