# How to invoke Linux shell env variable into vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

How to invoke Linux shell env variable into vimrc ?

I split vimrc configurations into multiple files and included these files in vimrc via `:runtime [file]`.
This works well.

```
:runtime vimrc.d/vimrc.pathogen           " pick one and comment others
":runtime vimrc.d/vimrc.vim-plug
":runtime vimrc.d/vimrc.vundle
```

After that, I want to define a variable in vimrc to specify which vimrc.x can be used.

A single or double quotation needed here for a vimrc variable

```
let vimrc_plugin_manager=pathogen      " It shows Undefined variable: aaa
let vimrc_plugin_manager="pathogen"    " both '' and "" here works find
```

The following doesn't work.

```
let vimrc_plugin_manager='pathogen'
:runtime vimrc.d/vimrc.&{vimrc_plugin_manager}    " This doesn't work
```

---

And finally, I want to move the variable from vimrc to shell ENV, and want it to be invoked in vimrc.

**Shell**

```
export VIMRC_PLUGIN_MANAGER=pathogen
```

**vimrc**

```
let vimrc_plugin_manager=&VIMRC_PLUGIN_MANAGER   " invoke shell env var to vimrc; seems not work
:runtime vimrc.d/vimrc.&{vimrc_plugin_manager}   " This doesn't work
```

How can it work?
I have searched a lot and havent' find solution yet.

Comment: Highly related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap your `:runtime` in an `:exec` you should be able to use your Vim variable.

```
let vimrc_customization='aaa'

:exec 'runtime vimrc.d/vimrc.' . vimrc_customization
```

Comment: Sorry I edit the question again and use my own case here. I tried  `let vimrc_plugin_manager='pathogen' ` and   ` :exec 'runtime vimrc.d/vimrc.'.vimrc_plugin_manager ` , the two blankspace removed , seems didn't work.

Comment: wrap `:runtime` in an `:exec` , YES,  it can work. `:exec 'runtime vimrc.d/vimrc.pathogen'`

Comment: Yes, It woks now.  Have to remove `:` before `runtime` and  concatenate string variables with `.`