# Custom key binding for project-wide search and replace using FZF.vim Rg function?

Tags: replace, plugin-fzf, ripgrep

I know that one can do a project-wide search and replace using the results of an Rg search in FZF.vim by doing the following:

1. Run `:Rg SEARCH_TERM`
2. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> (or in my case, <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, since I'm using xfce-4 terminal) to select all matches, or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> (or in my case, <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>) to deselect all matches. Press <kbd>CR</kbd> to open up the selected item in the current window. The quickfix list will be automatically populated with all selections.
3. Run `:cfdo %s/SEARCH_TERM/REPLACEMENT_TERM/g`

However, I'd like to see if I can create a custom binding for this.

I saw that someone else had the following solution using [mhinz/vim-grepper](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-grepper) by including this in his .vimrc:

```
let g:grepper={}
let g:grepper.tools=["rg"]

xmap gr <plug>(GrepperOperator)

" After searching for text, press this mapping to do a project wide find and
" replace. It's similar to <leader>r except this one applies to all matches
" across all files instead of just the current file.
nnoremap <Leader>R
  \ :let @s='\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>'<CR>
  \ :Grepper -cword -noprompt<CR>
  \ :cfdo %s/<C-r>s//g \| update
  \<Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
```

As this requires vimgrepper to be installed, I'm wondering if anyone has a solution that doesn't require vimgrepper and uses the Rg function in FZF.vim? I do project-wide search and replace quite often but would rather not have to install another plugin for this.

Comment: I think [Agriculture](https://jesseleite.com/posts/4/project-search-your-feelings) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No plugins:

- set the args list (e.g., `:args git ls-files`)
- search (`:vimgrep /pat/ ##`)
- replace (`:cdo substitute/...`)
- save (`:argdo update` or `:wall` or whatever)

Alternately, search with `:grep -R ... *` or set `grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep` and pretend `:grep` is ripgrep. Then `:cdo`, etc., as above.

I’m using `:cdo` because I’m assuming the search term is the same in both search and replacement. So the quickfix already has the relevant lines, making a global-search (`:cfdo %substitute`) less efficient. If the terms differ, `:cfdo` might be a better option.

Given that all these operations are rather simple ex-commands, it’s straightforward to wrap them in a function (perhaps with some parameters, which you [can use via `:execute`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604)). Then have a command or a mapping to call the function.