# Is it possible to call a shell command which includes default register contents inside a function?

Tags: functions, register

I want to write a function which opens a vim plugin's Github page, eg calling the function while on this line:

```
Plug 'tpope/vim-rhubarb'
```

... will do `!open https://github.com/tpope/vim-rhubarb`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function! PlugOpenGithub()
  normal 0f'yi'
  normal silent !open https://github.com/<C-R><CR>
endfunction
```

Invoking it doesn't seem to do anything: the browser doesn't open and there's no error message.

I tried removing the `<C-R><CR>` to see if that was the problem but still nothing happened.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604

Comment: @D.BenKnoble answered your question as stated.  To perform what you are trying to achieve, you can try this: `:call system("open https://github.com/" . getline(".")->matchstr("'.*'")[1:-2])`.  You probably want to do a bit more error checking to handle edge cases, but it may be a starter for your use.

Comment: Thank you both! I settled on this: `call system("open https://github.com/" . matchstr(getline("."), "\\v[^\"']+/[^\"']+"))`. It's not particularly robust but good enough for this purpose.

Comment: Please add an answer if you find something that works for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I settled on this:

```
call system("open https://github.com/" . matchstr(getline("."), "\\v[^\"']+/[^\"']+"))
```

It's not particularly robust but is good enough for this purpose.