# How to put sync region start=<this> into a variable?

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting, regular-expression, highlight

I have the following code:

```
com! -nargs=* ShFoldFunctions <args> fold
ShFoldFunctions syn region shFunctionOne start="^\s*[A-Za-z_0-9:,][-a-zA-Z_0-9:]*\s*()\_s*{"        end="}"
ShFoldFunctions syn region shFunctionTwo start="\%(do\)\@!\&\<[A-Za-z_0-9:,][-a-zA-Z_0-9:]*\>\s*\%(()\)\=\_s*{" end="}"
```

now I want to do:

```
let s:funcrgx = "[A-Za-z_0-9:,][-a-zA-Z_0-9:]*"
ShFoldFunctions syn region shFunctionOne start="^\s*".s:funcrgx."\s*()\_s*{" end="}"
ShFoldFunctions syn region shFunctionTwo start="\%(do\)\@!\&\<".s:funcrgx."\>\s*\%(()\)\=\_s*{" end="}"
```

but it does not work:

```
"/tmp/1.sh" 12L, 70B
Error detected while processing BufRead Autocommands for "*.sh"..function dist#ft#SetFileTypeSH[45]..dist#ft#SetFileTypeShell[21]..FileType Autocommands for
 "*"..Syntax Autocommands for "*"..function <SNR>9_SynSet[25]..script /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/sh.vim:
line  460:
E402: Garbage after pattern: "^\s*".b:funcrgx."\s*()\_s*{"<09><09>end="}"<09>contains=@shFunctionList<09><09> skipwhite skipnl nextgroup=shFunctionStart,shQ
uickComment
E475: Invalid argument: shFunctionOne<09>matchgroup=shFunction start="^\s*".b:funcrgx."\s*()\_s*{"<09><09>end="}"<09>contains=@shFunctionList<09><09> skipwh
ite skipnl nextgroup=shFunctionStart,shQuickComment
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Can I somehow move the repeated `syn start="<regex><regex>"` pattern to a variable so that it's not written multiple times?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:execute {expr1}` to execute the string that results from the evaluation of `{expr1}` as an Ex command.

```
execute "syn sync ...".s:funcrgx."..."
```

in place of `syn sync ...`