# How to create key-mapping for vimgrep with dynamic values for {file} argument

Tags: vimgrep

#### Problem

I am trying to create a more dynamic mapping for `vimgrep`. Many project directories I work in don't have consistent names for directories in which source/test code lives (ie. `test` vs. `tst`). I would like to run a command when I first begin a `vim` session at the root of the project to change the mapping for `vimgrep` to limit my searching to only user-provided directories.

The problem is that I am having difficulty creating a mapped expression to provide this functionality.

#### Desired workflow:

```
$ (.../proj_root) vim .

[in vim session]
:<user-command> src test
```

`:<user-command> src test` would execute the following and create the mapping:

```
:nn <c-\> :vimgrep /<c-r><c-w>/j src/** test/** <bar>:cw<cr>
```

#### Attempted solution:

{.vimrc}

```
command! -nargs=* ExeVpaths call ExeVpaths(<f-args>)
function! ExeVpaths(...)
    if len(a:000) == 0
        nn <expr> <c-\> printf(":vimgrep /<c-r><c-w>/j %s <bar>:cw<cr>", "*/**")
    else
        let l:vpaths = join(a:000, "/** ") . "/** "
        nn <expr> <c-\> printf(":vimgrep /<c-r><c-w>/j %s <bar>:cw<cr>", l:vpaths)
    endif
endfunction
```

#### Solution error

The above function executes with no errors for the following two examples:

```
(1) :ExeVpaths

(2) :ExeVpaths src test
```

However, using `<c-\>` after having run `(2)` fails with the two error messages:

```
E121: Undefined variable: l:vpaths
E116: Invalid arguments for function printf(":vimgrep /^R^W/j %s |:cw^M", l:vpaths)
```

This seems to be a scoping issue, seeing `l:vpaths` appears to be undefined. But that does not make sense to me because the variable is defined right above it.

Comments and critiques are appreciated.

Comment: Tip 1: Clearly `l:vpaths` is being evaluated when the mapping is executed and that won't work. You only have access to `l:vpaths` and its contained value when the function is running. Include the value  itself in the mapping...not the string 'l:vpaths'.

Comment: (Alternatively, if it is something you need to be evaluated when the mapping is keyed than you'd need to use a global variable...or get it from a function call.)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might be interested in [How do I use a variable or return value in option, command, or mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `l:vpaths` is no longer in context when the mapping is invoked, and the `printf()` will only be evaluated at invocation time.

Using a global variable (of buffer variable) would work to fix the issue here, since it would be available after the function has returned.

But I'm guessing what you want to do here is incorporate `l:vpaths` into the mapping that you define in the function.

You can easily do so by having your `printf()` produce the whole `nn` command and then use `execute` on it.

```
function! ExeVpaths(...)
    if len(a:000) == 0
        let l:vpaths = "*/**"
    else
        let l:vpaths = join(a:000, "/** ") . "/** "
    endif
    execute printf('nn <c-\> :vimgrep /<c-r><c-w>/j %s <bar>:cw<cr>', l:vpaths)
endfunction
```

Note that you don't need the `<expr>` anymore, since you're evaluating the `printf()` expression at the time when you're creating the mapping.