# How to `source` a path stored in a variable in Vimscript

Tags: vimscript, variables, execute

tldr: The title pretty much summarizes the entirety of the question

I am trying to make my configuration more adaptable to different machines so that I can use git to keep them in sync between my personal windows, linux, and work machines.
right now my `.vimrc`/`init.vim` passes absolute literal paths to the source key word and it works fine, but say I want to do something like this...

```
if has('win32')
   let prefix = $HOME . '/AppData/Local/nvim'
else
   let prefix = $HOME . '/.config/nvim'
endif

source prefix . '/vim-plug/plugins.vim'
```

This doesn't work because the `source` keyword interprets everything literally. So how can I make it expand the variables?

Here are some things i've tried

`source exec expand(prefix) . '/rest/of/path'`

`source <exec> expand(prefix) . '/rest/of/path'`

`source <exec> prefix . '/rest/of/path'`

`exec source prefix . '/rest/of/path'`

and many other variations

As I have been unsuccessful in finding an answer in a search engine, I've resorted to guessing different variations of this which is tedious and unproductive. So does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: `exe "source " . expand(prefix) . "/whatever.vim"`

Comment: awesome thank you.. This makes since too, now I think I understand what `exec` actually does

Comment: @MaximKim Please post as an answer... Thanks! (Or we can try to find a duplicate, if you prefer...)

Comment: @RileyHughes Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @filbranden [How do I use a variable or return value in option, command, or mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604)?

Answer (score 3):

`:h expand()` your string with environment variable,  concatenate it the rest and use `:h :execute` to source it:

```
:execute "source " . expand(prefix) . "/whatever.vim"
```

Comment: No need for `expand()` around `prefix`, it will already be evaluated since we're in an expression here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign a value for the path to a self defined *environment* variable (prefix: **$**, without $ it is a normal variable) and then use that environment variable, e.g.:

```
let $file_path = prefix . '/rest/of/path'
source $file_path
```

I don't know the reason, why Vim doesn't source a normal variable, but an environment variable.

Comment: It's because `:source` is an ex commands and does not expect an expression