# How can I use a variable line number with a command?

Tags: cursor-motions, variables, line-numbers, movement

I want to move a line to another specified in a variable.

So where I might do this to move the current line up seven lines:

```
:m-7
```

I want to do it with a variable line destination. Something like this:

```
:let lineOffset=-7
:m$lineOffset
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to append a collections of lines. So given this:

```
1
2
3
one
two
three
```

I want a simple way of getting this:

```
1 one
2 two
3 three
```

It seemed to me that the quickest way would be a macro. Something like this:

```
:m$(lineOffset)
kJ
$(lineOffset)j
:let lineOffset+=1
```

I know you can't use shell variable syntax as shown above. But used here for purpose of comprehension.

Where `lineOffset`, using the example above, would be -3, so would move the current line 3 lines back when used as `:m-3`.

And where those statements

1. Move current line to line number specified by `lineOffset` (move sends the cursor to that line as well);
2. Move to line above moved line and join it with the moved line;
3. Go to next line to be moved;
4. Set the `lineOffset` to the next line down from the last.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:g/^/m+2|j
```

to move the lines down by 2 and join with the next.

That applies the command to the whole document/buffer. As a side-effect, it leaves a search highlight on every line-start. `:nohlsearch` will clear the current search highlight. Additionally, a range can limit `global` to certain lines. So to apply it to only, say, lines 1 to 3, and remove the residual highlight:

```
:1,3g/^/m+2|j|noh
```

And if you really want a variable to be involved:

```
:execute("g/^/m+".lineOffset."|j")
```

Comment: What sort of magic is this? It worked! Oh I see: g applies command to every matching pattern, where: g/pattern/command. The command ^ selects every line-start, and m+2 moves each line down 2 lines. '|' tacks on another command, 'J', which joins the moved line with the one following.

Comment: But it's not J but j?