# How can I set path of vim from the shell command result

Tags: vimrc, path

I'd like to set c++ header file path automatically from .vimrc.
So I tried to write .vimrc file as shown below:

```
let g:gcpp_headers_path=system("g++ --version | grep g++ | awk '{print \"/usr/include/c++/\"$NF}'")

"if isdirectory(gcpp_headers_path)
  set path+=g:gcpp_headers_path
"endif
```

from the vimrc above I found the vim variable path set as shown below:

```
:set path?
path=.,/usr/include,,,g:gcpp_headers_path
```

The wanted output is as shown below:

```
:set path?
path=.,/usr/include,/usr/include/c++/7.5.0
```

I'd like to get this reviewed. Could someone advise me?

F.Y.I. The command in system() is shown below:

```
~$ g++ --version | grep g++ | awk '{print "/usr/include/c++/"$NF}'
/usr/include/c++/7.5.0
```

Comment: [How do I use a variable or return value in option, command, or mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the full implementation taken from my own config. Basically, run preprocessor, parse the output and cache the result. Then set path by ftplugin as needed.

> ~/.vim/autoload/misc.vim

```
" misc#gcc_include([{gcc} [, {force} [, {ft}]]])
" get GCC include dirs
function! misc#gcc_include(gcc = b:current_compiler, force = v:false, ft = &ft) abort
    let l:var = printf('%s_include_%s', fnamemodify(a:gcc, ':t:gs?[-.]?_?'), a:ft)
    if a:force || !has_key(s:, l:var)
        " $INCLUDE
        let s:[l:var] = split($INCLUDE, has('win32') ? ';' : ':')
        " builtin dirs
        let l:cmd = printf('%s -x%s -v -E -', a:gcc, a:ft is# 'cpp' ? 'c++' : a:ft)
        silent let l:include = map(systemlist(l:cmd, []), 'trim(v:val)')
        let l:ix1 = match(l:include, '#include <\.\.\.>') + 1
        let l:ix2 = match(l:include, '\.$', l:ix1) - 1
        if l:ix1 <= l:ix2
            let s:[l:var] += map(l:include[l:ix1 : l:ix2], 'simplify(v:val)')
        endif
    endif
    return copy(s:[l:var])
endfunction
```

> ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim

```
compiler gcc
let &l:path = misc#gcc_include()->insert('.')->add(',')->join(',')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's not that easy to understand though..

Comment: @Jumogehn Actually, this is more or less the same thing that LucHermitte had already explained. But this is complete and working implementation. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories

Answer (score 1):

This works!

```
let g:gcpp_headers_path = system("g++ --version | grep g++ | awk '{print \"/usr/include/c++/\"$NF}'")

execute 'set path+=' . g:gcpp_headers_path
```

This answer was given from stackoverflow user [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl)

References:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273958/how-can-i-set-path-of-vim-from-the-shell-command-result)
[there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915032/path-setting-for-c-include-headers-for-vim)

Answer (score 1):

I remember `system()` cannot be used from .vimrc because `'shellredir'` isn't set yet (see `:h starting`). This is odd you're able to make it work.

Because of that issue I had to ask for compiler system includes on `VimEnter` event -- in order to configure coc+ccls.

BTW I obtain the exact list of system includes with `g++ -E -xc++ - -Wp,-v < /dev/null`. The version number obtained through --version doesn't necessarily match the include directory, while this command give me the correct pathnames. For instance, my 7.5.0 g++ uses `/usr/include/c++/7` and not 7.5.0. Same issue with g++-8, 11, and so on.

IOW, IMO you'll want something like (untested code)

```
augroup SetSystemPaths
  au!
  au VimEnter * exe set path+=systemlist('g++ -E -xc++ - -Wp,v </dev/null')->filter({_,v -> =~ '^ '})->map({_,v -> substitute(v, '^ *', '', '')})->join(',')
augroup END
```

You may not want to keep every path. You can select them thanks to `filter()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But the filter() function is remained in a question. I select my own answer because it works. I wonder if there is any security issue with my answer. Anyway thank you for the answer!