# vim mapping diffput / diffget to Ctrl+Left / Ctrl+Right with working buffer selection from count

Tags: vimdiff, count, merge

Pretty new to mappings in Vim,

In Diff Mode I've got C-Up and C-Down mapped to `[c` and `]c` for diffjumping. I'm wanting to map `C-Right` and `C-Left` to `:<C-U>diffput v:count<CR>` and `:<C-U>diffget v:count<CR>` respectively to speed up merging.

```
nnoremap <C-Left> :<C-U>diffget v:count<CR>
nnoremap <C-Right> :<C-U>diffput v:count<CR>
nnoremap <C-Up> [c
nnoremap <C-Down> ]c
```

This should.... put from buffer # or get from buffer #.

But I get the error "no matching buffer for v:count".

the command looks to be taking `v:count` literally and running `:diffget v:count` instead of `:diffget 3` for example.. how do I get `v:count` to resolve to a number? like dereference the variable?

I can `echo "diffget v:count"` and that looks to be correct... but obviously doesn't do anything...

Comment: The right-hand side is the literal text you would type; as you already figured our it's not evaluated. To evaluate VimScript in there you can use an expression mapping by adding `<expr>`: `nnoremap <expr> <C-Left> ":\<C-U>diffget " .. v:count .. "\<CR>"`. Didn't test that so may not work exactly, but should point you in the right direction. Note that because it's a VimScript expression, you need to put literal text in strings. Special `<..>` only work in double-quoted strings as `"\<..>"`.

Comment: @MartinTournoij Worked Perfectly! Thanks - learning slowly! :) don't know how to add mark a comment as the answer..

Comment: What is the purpose of the " .. " if you don't mind explaining? Looks like concat for strings?

Comment: Well, you're not really supposed to answer questions in comments, so you can't accept it  As for the `..`, that's indeed just string concatenation. Actually just `.` also works, but `..` is the "new" way of doing it (it solves some ambiguity in some cases with `.` for other uses like decimals in numbers).

Comment: Thanks @MartinTournoij you're so helpful.

Comment: @MartinTournoij '<CR>' works fine in a expression mapping: I think because the expression is used as the rhs of the mapping, so it expands special keys in the same way as a regular :map command. See also the bottom pages paragraphs of `:h map-expr`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<expr>` as suggested in the comments, I would first try

```
nnoremap <C-Left> :<C-u>execute 'diffget' v:count<CR>
```

as in [How do I use a variable or return value in option, command, or mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604)