# How do I use variables with the delete command? (i.e., how to expand/reference variables for command arguments?)

Tags: vimscript, command-line, cut-copy-paste, variables, execute

I'm using variables for line numbers, and I want to delete a range of lines using these variables.  How do I do that?

```
    let x = 5
    let y = 20
    " I want to delete the range of lines from x to y (i.e., 5-20)
    " I guessed at this, but it doesn't work:
    x,ydelete
    " E15: Invalid expression: ",ydelete"
```

Extra credit for providing reference(s) to the vim documentation that explains this.  (I searched the docs for "variable" but didn't find what I needed)

Comment: rather than using variables, it might be easier to use marks, which do not need to be evaluated

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21392/how-do-i-use-a-variable-or-return-value-in-option-command-or-mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:execute` command, e.g.,

```
:execute x "," y "delete"
```

> :exe[cute] {expr1} ..
> Executes the string that results from the
> evaluation            of {expr1} as an Ex command.            Multiple arguments are
> concatenated...
> {expr1} is used as the processed command

[`:help execute`]

Edit: Per D Ben Knoble's comment, [How do I use a variable or return value in option, command, or mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21392/how-do-i-use-a-variable-or-return-value-in-option-command-or-mapping) addresses this question.