# VimScript: Substitute string variable content for string variable name

Tags: vimscript, variables

I would like to the present working directory (`:pwd`) be changed across all tabs and subwindows at the same time.  I tried:

```
let PreferredPWD=expand('%:p:h') " The desired working directory

" Need to replace PreferredPWD with its string.
" None of the following work:

tabdo windo cd PreferredPWD
cd(PreferredPWD)
cd &PreferredPWD
cd =PreferredPWD
cd $PreferredPWD
```

How does one replace the variable name with its contents?

**Afternote**

The following uses register ***a*** to work around my ignorance of how to replace a variable name with the variable content, but I'd still be interested in how such replacement is done in VimScript.

```
let @a=expand('%:p:h')
tabdo windo cd <Ctrl+R><Ctrl+A>
```

Comment: [How do I use a variable or return value in option, command, or mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change it to the content of `PreferredPWD` you can do:

```
:execute 'cd' PreferredPWD
```

If you have multiple tabs and multiple windows that have local working directory (`lcd`) you can change them all to the content of `PreferredPWD` with:

```
:tabdo windo execute 'cd' PreferredPWD
```

Remark: One of the usage of `execute` is that it let you use Vim expression to build your command.

Comment: For many years if not decades, I also believed that there was only one present working directory.  It may be the intended behaviour, but in many recent years, I have found that it is not the case in practice.  In view of this, your solution can be adapted for use across tabs and windows as `tabdo windo execute 'cd' PreferredPWD`.  BTW, I was wondering whether you might add to your answer and describe how to substitute a variable's content for its name in a VimScript command?  Thanks!

Comment: See `:h :lcd` and `:h :tcd`.

Comment: @romainl: How very interesting!  Vim as evolved.  Or maybe Vim always had this, and a portion of my awareness is trapped back in the "vi" stage.  However, I have never used `lcd` or `tcd`, so there must be some other avenue by which my tabs and subwindows got different *present working directories*.

Comment: @user2153435 thanks for the remark, I have learned something about the current working directory of windows in Vim ;-). I have adapted the solution accordingly.

Comment: `:tcd` is relatively new but `:lcd` has been there for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Like *most* Ex commands, at least those inherited from ex or inspired by it, `:cd` doesn't accept variables as argument but it can *expand* a bunch of things like `%`, documented under `:help cmdline-special`. In fact it also honors filename modifiers so you could simply do:

```
:cd %:p:h
```

If you still want to store that value, you can put it in a variable and then use `:help :execute`, as in the other answer, but there is another way that you unknowingly encountered while trying those various methods. Environment variables, also, are expanded on the command-line, so you could define one:

```
:let $PREFERRED_DIR = expand('%:p:h')
```

and use it directly with `:cd`:

```
:cd $PREFERRED_DIR
```

This is basically the same mechanism as in the popular `:so $MYVIMRC`.

Comment: Thanks, @romainl.  Yes, I do need to assign `%:p:h` to a persistent variable because `tabdo windo cd %:p:h`) causes `%` to be interpretted differently according to each individual subwindow.  My aim is to have all subwindows on the same *present working directory*. Since environmental variables are substituted in VimScript commands, that would do the trick. From the perspective of expediency, however, I may just resort to using a register.  It also keeps the environment unpolluted by non-environment information.

Comment: However, I would really like to know whether *in general* there is a way to cause variable substitution in a VimScript command before execution.  You said that `cd` doesn't accept variables, but aside from using environment variables, does VimScript have some mechanism for expanding non-environment variables in a command before execution?

Comment: I suppose this is one of the main purpose of `execute` put a side the possibility to concatenate commands with `|` that don't support it.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the purposes of `:execute`.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I'm going to see if I can mark both this and Vivian's answer as "the" answer.  I seem to recall that Stack Exchange limits this, but here goes...darn.  No can do.....