# Add a string at the beginning of a line through builtin functions

Tags: vimscript

I am practicing some vimscript and, although there are very good plugins out there, I am writing a function for commenting/uncommenting code for the matter of experimenting.

So far, I wrote the following:

```
def g:MyComment(comment_symbol: string)
    if trim(getline("."))[0] == comment_symbol
        normal! ^2x
    else 
        ?????
    endif
enddef

augroup commenting_blocks_of_code
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType c,cpp,java.      b:comment_symbol = '// '
    autocmd FileType sh,vim,python    b:comment_symbol = '# '
    autocmd FileType tex              b:comment_symbol = '% '
augroup END
```

The function works well for uncommenting one line.

However, I wish to add the string `comment_symbol .. " "`  at the beginning of the current line in position `^` but I cannot figure out how, i.e. I have to fill the `?????` line according to the mentioned requirements.

If possible, I would like to use builtin vim functions.

The next step would be to modify my function so that it can accept a `start_line` and an `end_line` as argument, i.e. I want to modify my function signature with `def g:MyComment(start_line: number, end_line:number, comment_symbol: string)` so that I can comment/uncomment a bunch of lines picked e.g. by a selection in Visual mode or by explicitly specifying a range.

Then, I can throw everything and install `vim-commentary`. :D

Comment: You might be interested in [How do I use a variable or return value in option, command, or mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put the value of `b:comment_symbol` at the beginning of a line, you can use

```
execute "normal 0i" . b:comment_symbol
```

Or, if you want to put your comment symbol before the first non-whitespace character (i.e. have your comments follow existing indentation), use

```
execute "normal I" . b:comment_symbol
```

Maybe there are more elegant solutions. I tried to find one that fits into the style of your code.

Having said that, I think that the `:substitute` command is much better suited for this task:

```
substitute/^/\=b:comment_symbol/
```

I also don't think that whitespace should be part of `b:comment_symbol`. Instead, it should be appended when inserting or removed when removing the comment. As your code is currently written, removing a C, C++ or Java comment will leave in one space while removing a comment from the (python) line `#foo` will chop off the `f`.

Comment: Thanks.  I agree, adding that whitespace may create troubles. Now I have everything working well in my .vimrc. However, when I open a .py file and i run the function I get E121: undefined variable b:comment_symbol. Do you know why?

Comment: @Barzi2001 That may be worth its own question. I did not try out your autocommands, instead I just did `:let b:comment_symbol='# '` for testing. In vim9script, `var` is used, while in legacy, it's `let`.