# How can I rename the current buffer to the current time?

Tags: command-line

I have tried

```
:file strftime("%H%M")
```

But this sets it to literally `"strftime("%H%M")"`.

My motivation for this is that I have a mapping for `:term cmake` and I end up with a bunch of terminal buffers that I have ran builds in; I would like them to be called e.g. `Build 4:06` and `Build 4:09` instead of `<PID>:cmake`.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:file` command only accepts a string while you need to evaluate an *expression*. The `:execute` command evaluates expressions and can be used to construct the command you want like this

```
:execute ':file Build' strftime("%H:%M")
```

Quoting from `:help :execute`:

> Executes the string that results from the evaluation
> of {expr1} as an Ex command.
> Multiple arguments are concatenated, with a space in
> between.

This first argument is simply your `:file` command with "Build" and the second argument is the current time.

Comment: It sounds like the equivalent of `eval` from various shell languages.