Store a windows path in a global variable and access it later?
I want to store a path in a global variable and then change to a directory.
:let g:OneDriveB='C:\Users\bram\SomeDrive\ -\ Das\ Company\ Name\'  # Works.
:cd g:OneDriveB # This second ex fails as the path not existing?


https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-25.14

Possible duplicate: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604

Is there something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions. I allow the question to rest :-)

Regular variables are not expanded in the context of Ex commands:
:cd g:OneDriveB
E344: Can't find directory "g:OneDriveB" in cdpath
E472: Command failed

so the usual workaround is to use :help :execute, as in Vivian's answer and Christian's comment. It is fine in a script but not very convenient in day-to-day command-line usage.
Environment variables, on the other hand, are expanded in the context of Ex commands:
:let $ONEDRIVEB = 'C:\Users\bram\SomeDrive\ -\ Das\ Company\ Name\'
:cd $ONEDRIVEB
:pwd
C:\Users\bram\SomeDrive\ -\ Das\ Company\ Name

so I recommend you use that instead because it is much simpler.
Note that environment variables don't have to be UPPERCASE, it is just a convention that I am used to.

And SO wouldn't be SO if it didn't feature a piece on environment variable capitalization. Bottom line, you're either doing it right or wrong, depending on how we interpret the answers. I habitually avoid capitalizing my own vars not to clash with bash. I'm either doing it wrong or right...

Anyway, nice answer. It's a solution I wasn't aware of. I'll try to keep it in mind.

Yeah, thanks for the pointer. Now the hardest part : reverting a 25 years habit.

it seems correct usage however, since :let $FOOBAR=1 is exported to the environment, see: vim --clean -c ':let $FOOBAR=1' -c '!bash -c "env |grep -i foo"'

Only in child shells, though, so I don't consider this a blocker.

It's open to interpretation and the question I linked was closed as opinion based. The main point, as I understand it, is that the whole POSIX zoo uses ALLCAPS. Avoid those names and you can never inadvertently interfere with one of those guys. I can set pager in blissful ignorance of some tool attributing meaning to PAGER. Does it for me. YMMV

I would do:
:execute 'cd ' . g:OneDriveB

Or:
:execute 'cd' g:OneDriveB


This is your first answer I had to save from the low quality posts queue not once but twice! For some reason, I find it incredibly funny.

Thanks @Friedrich. I understand that the first answer was a bit compact but the second is not really. Do you know the length criteria to consider it "low quality"?

I can only find "questions or answers that are very short". That said, in addition to "what to do", an answer should also tell "why" and point to the relevant documentation. "Give a man a fish…" and all that.

No, I don't know the criteria. I've done enough reviews (mostly on SO) to be completely puzzled. I somewhat suspect that code sections are not considered for length. I.e. your post would consist of four words. Just my guess, though. Somebody on [meta] may know.

You might add :execute 'cd ' .. g:OneDriveB and we'll see if it shows up a third time. No, just kidding :-D
