How do I cleanly set highlight colors based on the number of terminal colors?
My standard terminals have 256 colours, but I regularly have to use 8-colour terminals as well. For the terminals with more than 8 colours, I prefer highlight Comment ctermfg=DarkGrey, but on an 8-colour terminal this bolds the comments, which makes them stand out more than I'd like. I've also tried using ctermfg=Grey everywhere, but while this is fine on 8-colour terminals, it makes the comments too faint on terminals with more colours.
Currently, I'm working around this with the following code:
if &t_Co > 8
    let g:highlight_grey = "DarkGrey"
else
    let g:highlight_grey = "Grey"
endif
execute 'highlight Comment ctermfg=' . g:highlight_grey

This works, but doesn't seem terribly clean to me. Is there a better way of doing this?

What does "better" mean? Quick fixes: you can use a one-liner with a ternary (shortest, no global variable, readable only by C devs) or put the :highlight command with the respective color hardcoded below each branch of the conditional (shorter, no :execute, no global variable, code duplication). I guess you're looking for something else entirely?

@Friedrich Removing the global variable would be great; avoiding duplication and in generally being more concise is also an improvement. (For me, more concise generally equals more readable, unless it has to get really weird to get concise.) I have no difficulty with ternary operators, so that might be a good approach. Perhaps you could add an answer with your suggestions?

Also, that execute seems annoying to me; is there a way to directly substitute a variable when running an ex command, rather than building a string and passing it to an interpreter?

« Passing it to an interpreter »: I’m not sure what you mean. You get the same command-line parser used for all Ex commands with :execute. You can use printf() instead of string concatenation if you prefer. See also https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604

I agree with Friedrich: what does better mean?

Some cosmetic improvements are easily made ...
Use :execute with a ternary
execute 'highlight Comment ctermfg=' .. (&t_Co > 8 ? 'DarkGrey' : 'Grey')

This is only one line with the color names in a ternary operator (see :help ternary).
It's very concise and avoids the creation of a global variable.
For a thorough discussion of :execute and why it's needed, see How do I use a variable or return value in option, command, or mapping?
Use two :highlight commands
if &t_Co > 8
    highlight Comment ctermfg=DarkGrey
else
    highlight Comment ctermfg=Grey
endif

This is only one line less than the original code, works without the :execute command and a global variable. It duplicates (almost) one line of code.
I'd argue that either of these is better than the original code as it's a bit shorter and avoids global variables.
From the functional point of view, they're all the same.
Regardless of which solution you pick to move forward, you should turn your command into an autocommand as explained in :help colorscheme-override. This makes sure it is run when your colorscheme becomes active.
For example (using the shorter version purely to save me some typing):
augroup my_colorschemes
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme <your color scheme> execute 'highlight Comment ctermfg=' .. (&t_Co > 8 ? 'DarkGrey' : 'Grey')
augroup END

