# Vimscript: evaluating the contents of a variable

Tags: vimscript

I know I can evaluate a (visually) selected piece of vimscript by yanking it into a register and then executing the register with `:@registerName`.

Can this be done without clobbering a register e.g., by somehow executing the contents of a variable?

I've tried:

```
function! VimEval()
    let l:curQ = @" 
    yank
    let l:toEval = @"   
    let @" = l:curQ
    echo "TO EVAL:" . l:toEval
    echo "CURRENT:" . l:curQ
    l:toEval "<= THIS DOESN'T WORK
endfunction
```

But the last line of the function doesn't work like I expected it to.

Also, `@"` doesn't seem to work in the context of a function either:

```
function! SimpleVimEval()
    yank
    @"  "also doesn't work as expected
endfunction
```

I've tested the above with the following piece of vimscript in visual selection:

```
let inf = getbufinfo()
for key in inf
    echo key
endfor
```

Normal mode yank+":@" works, but neither `'<,'>call SimpleVimEval()` nor
`'<,'>call VimEval()` does.

Can they be made to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable in the expression of a 'normal' command?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9644/how-to-use-a-variable-in-the-expression-of-a-normal-command)

Comment: @LucHermitte Thanks, but not really. It should run in exec mode but e.g., in the `SimpleVimEval` version, I'm getting undefine inf variable errors which I don't get with a plain `y:@"` in normal mode.

Comment: why do you need a function instead of merely mapping `y:@"`?

Comment: @Mass I'd like to do it without clobbering the register. I already have a function that does selection-eval via a temp buffer, but it seems there should be a simpler way. I'm also curious as to why not even my `SimpleVimEval` function works the way I'd expect it.

Comment: What about `@=somevimexpression` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SimpleVimEval()` function isn't working because when you call a function with a range Vim will just call it repeatedly for each line in the range.

In the case of the specific expression you're trying to evaluate, a `for` line on its own doesn't make sense, neither does an `endfor`, and the line inside the `for` will fail since the `key` variable won't have been set.

You can fix that by defining the function using the `range` modifier, in which case Vim will call it only once when called with a range. It will then pass the function a pair of extra arguments, `a:firstline` and `a:lastline`, to let the function handle the range by itself.

In practice, that means you need to take those into account when executing the `yank` command. In this case, you need to use `execute` to assemble a command as a string, using the values of those two arguments. (See [`:help :execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) for more details if you're not familiar with it.)

This function definition will work for evaluating that `for` block when called with a range:

```
function! SimpleVimEval() range
  execute a:firstline "," a:lastline "yank"
  @"
endfunction
```

It turns out that the answer to your original question of how to execute a set of Ex commands without using registers is also `:execute`!

For example:

```
function! ArgVimEval(expr)
  execute a:expr
endfunction
```

And then you can call it with:

```
:call ArgVimEval("let inf = getbufinfo()\nfor key in inf\n    echo key\nendfor\n")
```

But it's much easier to call it with `:call ArgVimEval(@")` after yanking the visual selection if it's text from your buffer.

---

If you're trying to create a mapping to execute the current Visual selection, then I'd just use `@"` to execute it, but saving and restoring the original contents of the register around the operation.

Also, instead of a range function, I'd use the Normal mode `gv` command to select the last visual block, that way the command will still work with a blockwise or characterwise selection skipping some characters in some of the lines.

This implements what I just described:

```
function! ExecuteVisual()
  let save_reg = @"
  let save_regtype = getregtype('')
  try
    normal! gvy
    @"
  finally
    call setreg('', save_reg, save_regtype)
  endtry
endfunction
xnoremap <Leader>x :<C-U>call ExecuteVisual()<CR>
```

Comment: Before you posted the implementation, I did `function! VimEval() range
 let l:curQ = @"
    execute a:firstline "," a:lastline "yank"
 let l:toEval = @"
 let @" = l:curQ
 execute l:toEval
endfunction` (I really don't care about applying it to sub-line selections, & I like it also works on the current line if it's unselected). Should I also be using `setreg()`?

Comment: @PSkocik You need setreg for save and restore to preserve a copy of a visual block, that one behaves differently and needs to be restored with the proper options to be preserved correctly...